# Portable Virtual Box Error

Tags: virtualbox

I installed Portable Virtual Box in my flash memory.when I run it in my laptop it works great.but when I want to run it in my PC this error appears and it appears again when I run it as administrator.

```
Failed to create the Virtual Box COM object.

The application will now terminate.



Callee RC: E_NOINTERFACE (0x80004002)
```

Please help me.
Thanks a lot

Comment: What SO, versions, you use on both (laptop and PC)?

Comment: I need it in another PC in my uni and I'm testing it in my PC at home

Comment: What System Operative, versions (xp, vista, seven, 8, 8.1, etc), you use on both (laptop and PC)? If it are different, can be it the problem!

Comment: Both of them has win 7